# Can't update form data

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to edit form data by displaying the previous saved data on the form and then update it. It shows the data on the form which is saved in database but when i enter the new data it does not get the id of the row. I echo the update query, it shows the changed values but it shows id equals to empty. Here is my code for edit record and update; Edit record is working but update isn't:

```
    <?php

        include('connection.php');

        $id = ''; 
        if( isset( $_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id']; 
        }

        $udfname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["udfname"]);
        $udlname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["udlname"]);
        $udpwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["udpwd"]);
        $udeml = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["udeml"]);
        $udnum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["udnum"]);

        $query="UPDATE form
                SET fname = '$udfname', lname = '$udlname', pwd = '$udpwd', eml = '$udeml', num = '$udnum' 
                WHERE id='$id'";

        $res= mysql_query($query);
        if($res){
            echo "<p> Record Updated<p>";        
        }else{
            echo "Problem updating record. MY SQL Error: " . mysql_error();
        }
    ?>
```

Form for editing record:

```
    <?php
        include('connection.php');
        $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "";
            $fname = $row['fname'];
            $lname = $row['lname'];
            $pwd = $row['pwd'];
            $eml = $row['eml'];
            $num = $row['num'];        
        }
    ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Edit</title>
        <script>
        '
        '
        Jquery code here
        '
        '
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="update.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?=$id;?>">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="udfname" value="<?=$fname;?>"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="udlname" value="<?=$lname?>"><br>
            Password: <input type="text" name="udpwd" value="<?=$pwd?>"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="udeml" value="<?=$eml?>"><br>
            Contact Number: <input type="text" name="udnum" value="<?=$num?>"><br>
            <input type="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: stop writing new code with the deprecated API mysql

Comment: In first file, replace all `$_GET['id']` with `$_POST['ID']`

Comment: Still no result

Comment: I was taking id instead of ID

Answer (score 1):

At update time your form is submitted using POST request. So you need to get ID using POST method. So to get ID of hidden field change your code as below:

```
$id = ''; 
if( isset( $_POST['ID'])) {
    $id = $_POST['ID']; 
}
```

Comment: Answer updated. check once. As variables are case sensitive your hidden field name is `ID` you have to use it

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked; I was taking id instead of ID

Comment: Great. Glad to help @CaraJ. I have seen that you are not accepting answers of any. If answer solve your problem you need to accept answer as correct https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I amd sorry I don't know much about this site that's why

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
if( isset( $_POST['id']) && $_POST['id']!=null) {
    $id = $_POST['id']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear i think the problem with your method you are sending the data using post method and its very simple  instead of this code

```
if( isset( $_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id']; 
        }
```

write

```
if( isset( $_POST['id'])) {
            $id = $_POST['id']; 
        }
```

and one more thing that is you are using the mysql deprecated function for database kindly use the pdo for this or new mysqli functions.